# How to make gracefull by-user termination in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am doing bayessian hyperparameter search in Matlab. The process is infinite by nature, so I am showing the plot and have limits by number of iterations and time. Nevertheless, very often I see that the plot will not improve anymore and want to terminate the process. If I terminate script by force it will stop in random place and won't finish gracefully. I would like it to save best found combination so far.

Can I make a button or something, which could flag process to terminate gracefully and perform final operations?

Comment: Just add a button with [uicontrol](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) to your plot?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you could achieve this, from a figure with [uicontrol](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) helpers.

```
function pushbuttonPlot
f = figure;
ax = axes;

L = 160*membrane(1,100);
s = surface(L);
s.EdgeColor = 'none';
view(3)
ax.XLim = [1 201];
ax.YLim = [1 201];
ax.ZLim = [-53.4 160];

c = uicontrol;
c.String = 'Clean Up';
c.Callback = @cleanUpandExit;

    function cleanUpandExit(src,event)
        disp('Cleanup and exit');
        % Save data and exit
        close(f);
    end

end
```